# Sens de la phrase « descendre l'escalier »

Tags: sens

Comment distingue-t-on entre sens de la phrase « descendre l'escalier » ? Je crois que ceci peut signifier mouvement de sujet ( 1 ) aussi bien que mouvement de l'escalier se ( 2 ).

[image: descendre l'escalier - une image évidente]

Nouvelle information :

Il y a une échelle dans deuxième cas. Ma question est maintenant sur la phrase « descendre l'échelle » :-)

Comment: À droite c'est une échelle :-) Descendre un escalier avec le sens 2 c'est coriace.

Comment: @Stéphane, Oh, je ne savais pas! Escalier est seulement statique ?

Comment: [Pas toujours](http://www.conrad.fr/medias/global/ce/8000_8999/8900/8900/8905/890532_BB_00_FB.EPS_1000.jpg) mais c'est quand même assez rare.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A ma connaissance il n'y a pas de moyen de savoir si la phrase *"Descendre l'escalier"* signifie *Se déplacer dans l'escalier vers le bas* ou *effectuer un déplacement de l'escalier en direction du bas*.

Tout est une affaire de contexte mais heureusement dans l'immense majorité des cas, cela correspondra à la première signification. Un rare cas contraire qui me vient à l'esprit est celui des avions, où on parle parfois de "descendre l'escalier" pour désigner l'ouverture des [portes-escaliers](http://www.carnedvoyage.net/voyages/argentine/argentine_424.jpg).

Dans le cas d'une échelle qui est par définition moins statique, les deux sens peuvent être possibles et seul le contexte permet de faire la distinction.

(Bien entendu, il en va de même pour *"monter l'escalier/l'échelle"*...)

A noter que l'expression *"descendre de l'escalier/l'échelle"* est elle plus claire puisqu'elle n'a qu'un seul sens, différent des deux autres : celui de quitter par le bas l'escalier (ou l'échelle) où on se trouve.